# CakeEmail Could Not Send Email

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I need help guys. I can't get this working. Could you help me?

Thanks in advance!

**config/email.php**

```
public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'sender@yahoo.com',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

FeedbacksController.php

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
*
*
*
public function send() {
     $email    = new CakeEmail('default');
     $email->emailFormat('text')
           ->to('recipient@yahoo.com')
           ->from('sender@yahoo.com')
           ->send('Message Body');
}
```

The above code gives me an error:

Could not send email.

```
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

Comment: Have you got your debug level set to 2? (in 'app/Config/core.php' have `Configure::write('debug', 2);` Do you get more information on the error when this is set?

Comment: CORE\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php line 972 → MailTransport->send(CakeEmail)


APP\Controller\FeedbacksController.php line 82 → CakeEmail->send()
[internal function] → FeedbacksController->send()


CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php line 488 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(FeedbacksController, array)


CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 103 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)


CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 85 → Dispatcher->_invoke(FeedbacksController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)


APP\webroot\index.php line 96 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)

Comment: do i need to provide my username and password for the "sender@yahoo.com" email?

Comment: No, you'd have to do that if you were using the SMTP transport.

Comment: Have you had php's `mail()` function to work on your server before? ([php.net/mail](http://php.net/mail))

Comment: Just now I used that function.

mail ( 'sender@yahoo.com' , 'subject' , 'message', 'recipient@yahoo.com');

It returned: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :
In the app/config/email.php add this new config

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'adresse@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'timeout' => 1
);
```

After that and in your controller you have to call :

```
$email    = new CakeEmail('gmail');
```

That is it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience ive had issues setting the ->from to a single string, and have found that doing ->from(array('emailaddress' => 'name')) has been more successful.

Also im not sure if setting a subject value is required to work sucessfully?